# Change Toolbar Items Background ios

Tags: ios, toolbar

Is it possible to change Toobar Items (2) Background Image or Color when i click on a button (1)

[image]
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can always use the view of an uibutton like this:

```
UIButton* button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)]; //or the size you need
```

//now you can set an image

```
[button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

//or you can change the background or anyother stuff

```
[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[botonFav setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES]; //optional
[botonFav addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
self.yourButton = btn;
```

//and you should implement the button action like this:

```
-(void)buttonAction{
    //your code here
}
```

I hope this was what you where looking for

Comment: Thanks for your response, but what i want is when i click on button "Button" (1) i can change the background of UIToolbar button which is named in the image above "item"(2).Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a property for item2 button by ctrl+dragging from interface Builder to your header file.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) UIButton *item2Button;
```

From your button1, create an IBAction by ctrl+drag from button to header file setting it as an action

```
-(IBAction)buttonOnePressed:(id)sender;
```

In your implementation file, within this IBAction method, you will be able to change the properties of the item2Button as you require.

Assuming you already have a button background UIImage ready for item2Button called something like **buttonImage**, then within the IBAction method enter this

```
[self.item2Button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I hope this is clear,

Cheers, Jim.